# Nonsensical result in the midst of calculating an integral via substitution.

Tags: calculus, trigonometry, definite-integrals

I was just calculating an integral via a trigonometric substitution and ended up with $\color{red}{ \text{something pretty nonsensical} }$ but $\color{blue}{ \text{reversing the substitution} }$ seemed to clean it up.
$$\begin{aligned} \int_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \dfrac{\text{d}\theta}{3+5\cos \theta} \ & \overset{t=\tan \frac{\theta}{2}}= \ \dfrac{1}{4} \color{red}{ \log \left| \dfrac{2+t}{2-t} \right| \Bigg|}_{\color{red}{0}}^{ \color{purple}{\infty  }}  \\ & \ \ = \dfrac{1}{4} \color{blue}{ \log \left| \dfrac{2+\tan\frac{\theta}{2}}{2-\tan\frac{\theta}{2}} \right| \Bigg|_{0}^{\frac{\pi}{2}} } \end{aligned}$$
Why is that the case? Is it something to do with the nature of the substitution? 
Is there something I'm not considering when performing the substitution?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you.

**Edit**: It turns out that $\color{purple}{\tan\frac{\pi}{4} =1}$. Problem solved!

Comment: Why do you think it's nonsensical? (It may be, but it doesn't _immediately_ seem wrong to me.)

Comment: Probably because it doesn't look natural (compared to the things I've already seen) to me. It doesn't look well defined. It's essentially taking the logarithm of an infinitely large number which is divided by an infinitely large number, @Semiclassical.

Comment: $\tan\theta/2$ goes from $0$ to $1$ when $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\pi/2$.

Comment: WA gives a final answer of $\frac{1}{4}\log 3$, which is consistent your second expression if you account for with ThomasAndrew's remark above.

Comment: @Semiclassical The integrand is clearly positive, but the (red) right side is zero at $t=0$ and $t=\infty$.

Comment: @Khallil $\lim_{t\to\infty} \left|\frac{2+t}{2-t}\right|=1$, so it isn't nonsensical, but the real problem is that the right value is zero at $t=0$ and $t=\infty$, and the integrand is positive.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: I was actually focusing on his final expression, which is in fact correct since $\tan \frac{\pi}{4}=1$ (his back-substitution of $x=\tan\frac{\theta}{2}$ undoes the mistake in limits).

Comment: But he clearly marked the middle one as the non-sensical one (with the colorings in the question) and said the final expression was not nonsensical. Maybe that was added a few edits after your comment. @Semiclassical

Comment: It was. Sorry for the confusion, guys!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When $\theta$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}2$, $\frac{\theta}2$ goes from $0$ to $\frac{\pi}4$ so $\tan\frac{\theta}2$ goes from $0$ t0 $1$, not $0$ to $\infty$.

Comment: :O - I can't believe I didn't see that. Thanks, @Thomas!

Comment: It's not an uncommon mistake :) @Khallil